# Sennheiser PC360 Microphone Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, headset

Just recently, my [Sennheiser PC360's](http://www.sennheiser.ca/live/senn/produit/en/2813/) microphone stopped working. Yesterday Night, it was working 100% fine. Muting correctly, un-muting, volume boosting, etc. I woke up this morning, and got into a skype call (After not changing a single setting on my computer), and it wasn't working. I tried mumble, and it didn't work there either. After that, I checked my sound devices and found out it was plugged in, but not responding to my voice. I unplugged the headset, and it correctly showed that it was unplugged. So, a quick run-down:

- Sennheiser PC360 Headset suddenly stops working after a few hours of sleep.
- Software is up to date
- I can hear the mute sound when I raise and lower the microphone arm
- Windows Sound Device Manager shows that it is plugged in
- Unplugging the headset correctly shows it is unplugged
- Windows Sound Device Manager shows that the microphone isn't receiving any input

Comment: Have you tested it on a different computer to determine if the mic is defective?

Comment: If you use System Restore back to a point when it was working, does it work?

Comment: Spilled something on mic? I once accidentally sneezed into mine and it never worked thereafter! :D

Comment: @techie007: That's a big leap for stupid microphone!

Comment: @tumchaaditya Going to a System Restore point from back to a day to two ago isn't really a big deal. Really though, he should try it on another system first.

Comment: Provided he has a point a day or two old...if you leave restore point creation to system, chances are you'll have a stale restore point most of the times when you need it...anyways, thats not a debate here....system restore is still a good way which I myself have used numerous times..